# Grouping By repeated item List

Tags: java-8

I've a `List<Provider>` with a `List<Invoice>` inside; I'd like re-order it like follow:

```
public class Provider {
    Long idProvider;
    String name;
    List<Invoice> invoiceList;
    ...
}

public class Invoice {
    Long idInvoice;
    Integer order;
    BigDecimal value;
    LocalDate dueDate;
    ...
}
```

However each `Provider` it is filled more than once in a list, and I need to re-order it so that repeated `Providers` stay in a single one, and all the others `Invoice` make it together; Like that:

**Provider_A** *(record 1)*

- Invoice_1
- Invoice_2

**Provider_A** *(record 2)*

- Invoice_3

**Expected:**

Provider_A

- Invoice_1
- Invoice_2
- Invoice_3

I tried using `Collectors.groupingBy` and it works, but it returns a `Map<Long, List<Provider>>` and it must be a List. I was thinking of using this and then switching to a list, but it looks like a workaround, maybe does it have a better way grouping by return a `List<Provider>` straight away. Any helps?

Comment: wait, what? What is the expected result again?

Comment: So you mean to say by provider name try to merge invoice list?

Comment: It must return a java.util.List @Eugene; And yes @manfromnowhere by provider name, to merge the invoice list, and return as a java.util.List

Comment: in such a case just wrap the result if my answer into an `ArrayList`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
yourListOfProviders
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Provider::getIdProvider,
             Function.identity(),
             (left, right) -> {
                 left.getInvoiceList().addAll(right.getInvoiceList());
                 return left;
             }))
   .values();
```

Comment: Hey @Eugene, on 'left' and 'right' variables, it is not possible get the attribute, it just allow to get 'class'; left.getClass() and right.getClass()... it is an Object. How did you get the attributes from 'Provider'?

Comment: @fernandokarpinski I created some small classes in my IDE just now according to your code, and it works just fine for me, might be an IDE issue?

Comment: You have to specify the type.

Comment: @m4gic unless of course it is inferred by the compiler, and they *should* be inferred.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately my Eclipse complained when I tried not to specify them (and yes, it "inferred" the Object type...)

Comment: @m4gic did you try javac? might be an eclipse issue here

Comment: Interesting. I was able to compile (mine) with javac it without types (IDE still complaints). Your version compiles in the IDE and using javac too. Maybe I bumped into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016329/cannot-use-java-8-method-with-lambda-arguments-without-specifying-type-arguments)

Comment: Yes guys, it is weard, by using eclipse IDE Ctrl+Space it is not allowed however wheter write it manually, it works! I'll accept the answer and thank you all for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

A more painful way:

```
        Collection<Optional<Provider>> ovalues =   
                 yourListOfProviders.stream().collect(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(
                         Provider::getIdProvider, 
                         Collectors.reducing((Provider left, Provider right) -> {
                             left.getInvoiceList().addAll(right.getInvoiceList());
                             return left;
                         })
                     )
                 ).values();
        List<Provider> values = ovalues.stream().map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer also, btw it's more ellegant and eclipse IDE autocomplete with ctrl+space, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks :) However when I saw Eugene's post I almost throw my version out :) I posted as a deterrent example. If you give it up too soon, you will get this kind of result.